# The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request (Flask)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, flask

I have a Flask project working well on local machine. Now, I am trying to deploy it on Microsoft Azure server (Linux 17), but when I click on a button, it gives me an error.

```
@app.route('/database', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(werkzeug.secure_filename(f.filename))
        Finaldata = readFile(f.filename) # a function to read the uploaded file, request and API then process the data. Create a new file and write the output to
        filename = Finaldata

        @after_this_request
        def remove_file(response):
            try:
                os.remove(f.filename)
                # readDate.readerIn.close()
            except Exception as error:
                app.logger.error("Error removing or closing downloaded file handle", error)
            return response


        def download(response):
            response = make_response(Finaldata)
            response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.txt"
            render_template('upload.html', filename=filename)
            return response
        return render_template('upload.html', filename = filename)
```

My HTML code:

```
<form action = "/database" method = "POST"
     enctype = "multipart/form-data" class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large w3-margin-top">
     <input type = "file" name = "file" />
     <input type = "submit"/>
  </form>
```

Error message on the browser:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Error message in the logs:

```
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103627 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358] [2018-04-17 17:40:07,100] ERROR in app: Exception on /database [POST], referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103675 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103685 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app, referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103693 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]     response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103701 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103709 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103717 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception, referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103725 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103795 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise, referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103806 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]     raise value, referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103813 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103821 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]     rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103829 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request, referer: http://52.186.71.2/
[Tue Apr 17 17:40:07.103836 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31304:tid 140188999214848] [client 134.193.130.121:41358]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer: http://52.186.71.2/
```

Comment: You have taken your log output from a console that *truncates the data*. We can only see the WSGI server prefixes to the lines (such as the PID and IP address), but the information we need has been mostly truncated.

Comment: I can *just* about make out there is a permission error with some kind of file. IS your code trying to save something on the server? Then your process does not have permission to do so.

Comment: You want to read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/#a-gentle-introduction carefully; you are trying to save the files relative to the current working directory, *and you usually don't know where that is* on a WSGI server. Use an absolute path instead. The linked page uses an explicit `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']` path.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is what is the server provided for me!

Comment: Thank you so much. But why is there a permission error while I am running it as the root?

Comment: The server would not have provided the `$` entries on the right.

Comment: So I do not have the permission to save a file on the server ?

Comment: Your WSGI process won't be running as root, at least, I'd hope not.

Comment: You are saving your files in the *wrong place*.

Comment: To determine where you *should* save your files, take a look at the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).  It gives a rough map of how most Linux filesystems are laid out.  You don't have to memorize it, but use it as a reference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you. I fixed the server error message